# gdalwarp with NETCDF files

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, netcdf

I have been looking for it for a while but couldn't find what exactly I need.

I have WRF outputs in NETCDF format and I want to convert them to Geotiffs with gdalwarp.

I think my -s_srs should be this one because I used lambert : http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/29/
and my -t_srs should be this one since I want albers : http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6630/

By the way I want the QFX subdataset.

When I do this I receive an error:

```
gdalwarp NETCDF:wrfout_d01_2007-06-01:QFX -s_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-97 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs" -tr 12000 12000 -of GTIFF output.tiff
```

and the error is this:

```
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
ERROR 1: Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line
and georeferenced coordinates for NETCDF:wrfout_d01_2007-06-01:QFX.
There is no affine transformation and no GCPs.
```

So it requires some GCP but I do not know how to provide them. 
Also the latitude and longitude is in the NETCDF as subdatasets.

Comment: Ultimately the GCPs are those long/lat arrays, but you may not need any "warping" to re-establish the original LCC projection. Can you point to an example file somewhere? If the creators have smashed/lost the original projection sometimes you can recover with a bit of detective work, or it may be as simple as re-assigning it with gdal_translate's arguments "-a_srs" and "-a_ullr". If you think the data is in LCC but it ships with longlat arrays, then there's a disconnect in there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem with -a_ullr option in 2 steps. First I used: gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr -106.47828674316406 44.88469696044922 -93.026123046875 37.8767204284668 -a_srs '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'  NETCDF:wrfout_d01_2007-06-01:QFX output.tiff     then I used gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs" -tr 12000 12000 output.tiff albers_output.tiff and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from the comments:

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr -106.47828674316406 44.88469696044922 -93.026123046875 37.8767204284668 -a_srs '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' NETCDF:wrfout_d01_2007-06-01:QFX output.tiff
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs" -tr 12000 12000 output.tiff albers_output.tiff
```