# Reprojecting netcdf file using gdalwarp?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, utm

My netcdf file coonsists of radar rainfall data in aeqd projection (azimuthal equidistant projection). Each file consists of 5952 timestamps(7.5 minutes resolution) of rainfall values for 1kmx1km grids.

I want to reproject from aeqd to UTM33 using gdalwarp in commandline as follows.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -of netCDF C:/Radar/precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc C:/Radar/RadarPrecip_UTM33proj.nc
```

I get error message that

> Input file C:/Radar/precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc has no raster bands.

Why do I get this error message?

I want to get output as reprojected netcdf file with utm33 1kmx1km grids.

Comment: You need to specify the subdataset to warp. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123107/gdalwarp-with-netcdf-files for the syntax. gdalinfo tells you the name of the subdatasets.

Comment: By using gdalinfo, I found the subdatasets  as follows.
 Subdataset_1 - equivalent_reflectivity_factor    [5545x480x480]
  Subdataset_2 - lat
  Subdataset_3 - lon
  I am not clear how to specify the subdataset to warp.

Comment: The srcfile part of gdalwarp has to be something like `NETCDF:"path/to/file/filename":subdatasetname`.

Comment: I modified as you advised and run. I got the following warnings. Warning 1: NetCDF driver detected file type=5, but libnetcdf detected type=3.  Warning: The target file has a 'nc' extension, which is normally used by the GMT, netCDF drivers, but the requested output driver is GTiff. Is it really what you want?
Anyhow, I got the output file. However, when I open the file using netcdf4/Python, I get error message that file is not netcdf file format.

Comment: Can you add the new command line to your question?

Comment: Here is the new command line. 'gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=59.458925 +lon_0=10.564472 +R=6371000 +datum=WGS84" -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -tr 1000 1000 -of netCDF C:/Radar/precip_aeqd-1000.201408 C:/Radar/RadarPrecip_UTM33proj.nc'

Comment: I don't see any reference to the subdataset to be warped.

Comment: Sorry,  This is the new command line. 'gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=59.458925 +lon_0=10.564472 +R=6371000 +datum=WGS84" netCDF:C:/Radar/precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc:equivalent_reflectivity_factor -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -tr 1000 1000 C:/Radar/RadarPrecip_UTM33proj.nc'

Comment: This command line misses the `-of netCDF` option for the target file, which you had earlier. `netCDF:` is for the source file.

Comment: I modified the command as follows 'gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=59.458925 +lon_0=10.564472 +R=6371000 +datum=WGS84" netCDF:C:/Radar/precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc:equivalent_reflectivity_factor -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -tr 1000 1000 -of netCDF C:/Radar/RadarPrecip_UTM33proj.nc'  I get error messages. Then I found in the subdataset that it is HDF5 **SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF5:"C:/Radar/precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc"://equivalent_reflectivity_factor**  I replaced netCDF with HDF5 in the command line, then I get the error message

Comment: When I use this command 'precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc"://equivalent_reflectivity_factor -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -tr 1000 1000 -of netCDF "C:/Radar/RadarPrecip_UTM33proj.nc"://equivalent_reflectivity_factor'
ERROR 1: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for HDF5:C:/Radar/precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc://equivalent_reflectivity_factor. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.

Comment: I uploaded the file.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gma8h62te79qwx/precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working in two steps for the first band:

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -240500 240500 239500 -239500 -a_srs "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=59.458925 +lon_0=10.564472 +R=6371000 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs" -a_nodata 9.96921e+036 -b 1 HDF5:"precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc"://equivalent_reflectivity_factor precip-aeqd-1.tif
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:25833 -tr 1000 1000 precip-aeqd.tif precip-utm-1.tif
```

This does not use the geoloc information in subdataset 2 and 3, but the corner coordinates from those subdatasets, converted to aeqd with

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=aeqd +lat_0=59.458925 +lon_0=10.564472 +R=6371000 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs corners.txt >aeqd.txt
```

and added 500m offset from mid cell to the edge. I omitted `datum=WGS84` from the projection because this conflicts with the given radius.

This is my result, with the corner points from the subdatasets 2 and 3:

[image]

For all 5545 bands, you better use a vrt file:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_ullr -240500 240500 239500 -239500 -a_srs "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=59.458925 +lon_0=10.564472 +R=6371000 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs" -a_nodata 9.96921e+036 HDF5:"precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc"://equivalent_reflectivity_factor precip-aeqd.vrt
gdalwarp -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -t_srs EPSG:25833 -tr 1000 1000 precip-aeqd.vrt precip-utm.tif
```

but the resulting tif is 2.4GB even with compression.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working well  but I did some modifications.. When I use your aeqd projection text, output does not placed right location. I used aeqd projection from metadata and used it "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=59.458925 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs" and instead of 240000, I used 240500. It reprojected to right position.

Comment: By using gdal_translate - of VRT, I got  precip-aeqd.vrt and then used gdalwarp to the fianl output file precip-utm.tif. I get warning as follows. **Warning 1: Metadata exceeding 32000 bytes cannot be written into GeoTIFF. Transferred to PAM instead.**

Comment: This warning is a restriction of the GeoTIFF format. Are you sure about `+lon_0=0`?

Comment: As I asked initially, can I get the final output as netcdf file after reprojection?

Comment: _Are you sure about +lon_0=0?_ Yes,I think. I got the projection text from the file metadata. Further, I plotted the output in Arcmap. It placed on the right location.

Comment: I tried netcdf, but got a warning about exceeding size. http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html says 2GB for netcdf.

Comment: Thanks. The size of the original file(precip_aeqd-1000.201408.nc) is 239MB only.  Now I wonder, is it possible from VRT to NetCDF?

Comment: I tried that and failed. Maybe they did a better compression with unwarped cell values. Now I converted the corner coordinates from subdataset 2 and 3 to aeqd, and adjusted the extent which is 500m off the cell values. I'm still not convinced about `lon_0`. it should be mid-map around 10°E , not Greenwich.